# Find the area of largest rectangle that can be inscribed in a circle

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> What is the rectangle with the largest area and perimeter that can be inscribed in a circle with radios $R$

$A(\theta)=4R^2cos(\theta)sin(\theta)$

$A'(\theta)=4R^2(cos^2(\theta)-sin^2(\theta)$

$0=4R^2(cos^2(\theta)-sin^2(\theta)$

$\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$

$A''(\theta)=-8R^2(cos(\theta)sin(\theta))$

$A''(\frac{\pi}{4})=-8R^2(cos(\frac{\pi}{4})sin(\frac{\pi}{4}))=-2R^2<0$

I got $\frac{\pi}{4}$ also for $P(\theta)=2Rcos(\theta)+2Rsin(\theta)$.

1. Is the following right?
2. if I would look for the minimum area and perimeter, I could I find it If I got just 1 point that is a maximum?

Comment: What is $\theta$? Is it the angle between the 2 diagonals?

Comment: Sorry, $\theta$ is the angle between the diagonal and the width (the 90 degree triangular)

Comment: The area should be $4R^2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: i have got $$A=4R^2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$$

Comment: @Element118 right , but because I am trying the derivative it does not effect

Comment: The perimeter should be $4R(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)$.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner edited

Answer (score 0):

The answer for largest rectangles are always squares if possible.  So the answer would an inscribed square, much easier than all of your calculations.

The minimum rectangle would have a side length of $0$ units, giving it no area and minimum perimeter.  The perimeter would be double the radius of the circle by obvious observations.